# Create Nested Object which contains N' nested objectsfrom .txt file Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

After lots of tries and searching I decide to ask because I am stuck.I have a txt file like this:

---

```
CITYS
CITYS.AREAS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.KITCHEN
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TV
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE.VASE
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE.ASTREY
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE.SHAMPOO
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE.CONTITIONER
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.POOL
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.POOL.WATER
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.TREE.....
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.BRAND...
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.BRAND.LOGO.....
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.COLOR..
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.TYPE..
```

---

And I want to convert it into a nested object like this

---

```
    CITYS:{
    AREAS:{
        STREETS:{
          HOUSES:{
           ROOMS: {        
                LIVINGROOMS: {TV,TABLE:{VASE,ASTREY}},
                BATHROOMS:  {BATHTUBE:{SHAMPOO,CONTITIONER},MIRROR},                    
                ...
            },              
            GARDEN:{
                    ......              
            },
          },             
         CARS:{              
            BRAND:{LOGO},
            COLOR:{},
            TYPE:{},                
            ......
            },              
        },
    }   
}
```

---

I am tring to do somthing like that (IN ARRAY)

```
for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){

    var n = lines[line];
    var ninpieces = n.split(".");
    var name=ninpieces[ninpieces.length-1];
    var nametostore=ninpieces[ninpieces.length-2]   ;

      CreateObject(name,nametostore);
};

CreateObject=function(name,nametostore){

this.a= name;
this.b= nametostore;

newpar=this['b'];
newchild=this['a'];
this[newchild]=new Array();


if (typeof this[newpar] != "object") {
this[newpar]=new Array();
}

this[newchild].push(name);
this[newpar].push(this[newchild])
stractureobj.push(this[newpar])
}
```

Is a combination of things that I found here in stackoverflow but it's not working.

Comment: show how did you get and parse  that `txt` file in code

Comment: `{VASE,ASTREY}` is not valid object notation. It should be something like `{VASE: 1,ASTREY: 1}`

Comment: @trincot `{VASE,ASTREY}` is valid using destructuring

Comment: Where is `stractureobj` defined?

Comment: @guest271314, that is true, but what I want to say is that in the way it is used in the question, it is invalid as it has nothing to do with desctructuring.

Comment: Thank you for your really fast replies.
@guest271314 stractureobj  is global object.

Comment: the easy way is to create something that self-creates arbitrary nested paths of almost-empty objects, then you can feed them all in a row, without concern to ordering or "conch passing", merging the results, or merging up-front in the shell maker with some sort of default routine on each step of the object-building loop.

Comment: @trincot I am not sure if it is valid object notation but i made this example to show you what i expect as result from the function.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i get this file as export from a program and is all I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code. This "algorithm" temporarily stores also properties by their fully dotted names, as synonyms for the corresponding nested objects. This way it can quickly retrieve where to inject the next line's object.

Note that the algorithm performs fastest if the input is sorted. This you can do with `lines.sort()` if necessary.

```js
function addNestedObject(obj, lines) {
    var map = { '': obj }; // Set starting point for empty path
    function addLine(line) {
        var name = line.split(".").pop();
        var path = line.substr(0, line.length-name.length-1);
        if (!map[path]) addLine(path); // recurse to create parent
        if (!map[line]) map[line] = map[path][name] = {}; // set name & line synonym
    }
    // Process each line with above private function.
    for (var line of lines.slice().sort()) addLine(line);
    return obj; // Might be useful to have as return value as well 
};

// Sample input
var lines = [
    'CITYS.AREAS',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TV',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE.VASE',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE.ASTREY',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE.SHAMPOO',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE.CONTITIONER',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.POOL',
    'CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.POOL.WATER',
    'CITYS',
];

var stractureobj = { 'otherProperty': 42 };

// Convert lines to nested object and add to stractureobj
addNestedObject(stractureobj, lines);

// Output in snippet
document.querySelector('pre').textContent=JSON.stringify(stractureobj, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

The above uses an object `stractureobj`, with already its own properties, to which the nested structure must be added.

If you are only interested to have an object with just the nested structure, and nothing else, you could call it with the empty object and assign the return value:

```
var stractureobj = addNestedObject({}, lines);
```

Which comes down to the same as this:

```
var stractureobj = {};
addNestedObject(stractureobj, lines);
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend for your help.Your answer is what i asked for but when i use it on my real document it didn't work because i didn't know that i had something like :
      CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.KITCHEN
      CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TV
Thanks again for your help

Comment: I see. Although you already accepted an answer, I still have updated my answer to create the objects that are missing due to such "missing" lines.

Comment: i accidentally press enter before finish my comment and sound rude.. sry :)
I believe that if i knew that i have some elements like those i said above and include them in my answer your code will be perfect. guest271314 answer is working for my file. I want also to ask you :
My next step is to transform that txt file to html like this : <div id="CITYS.AREAS" ><div id="CITYS.AREAS.STREETS "><img alt="CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TV"></div></div> and so on. Does my approach to convert it first to obj and the try export it to html is good or there is a better way.

Comment: Just note that my answer has been updated since your first comment, so it now works as well for the case you put in the first comment. As to your follow-up question: yes, creating the object structure is certainly a nice approach to get to that HTML.

Comment: Yep it works perfect. Thank you very much i can work with it :)
And also thx for useful comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/\n/` as parameter to split text file at new line characters, `Array.prototype.filter()` with parameter `Boolean` to remove empty items from array; set `stractureobj` to an empty object; use single `for` loop, `Array.prototype.reduce()` to set properties of `stractureobj`

```
for (var line = 0
     , stractureobj = {}
     , lines = textFileContents.split(/\n/).filter(Boolean)
     ; line < lines.length
     ; line++) {
  var n = lines[line];
  if (line === 0) {
    stractureobj[lines[line]] = {}
  } else {
    var ninpieces = n.split(/\./).filter(Boolean);
    ninpieces.reduce(function(obj, prop, index) {
      var curr = ninpieces[index + 1];
      if (!obj[prop] && !!curr) {
        obj[prop] = {
          [curr]: {}
        };
      } else {
        if (obj[prop] && curr 
          && !obj[prop][curr]) {
            obj[prop][curr] = {}
        }
      }
      return obj[prop]
    }, stractureobj)
  }
};
```

```js
for (var line = 0
     , stractureobj = {}
     , lines = document.querySelector("pre")
               .textContent.split(/\n/).filter(Boolean)
     ; line < lines.length
     ; line++) {
  var n = lines[line];
  if (line === 0) {
    stractureobj[lines[line]] = {}
  } else {
    var ninpieces = n.split(/\./).filter(Boolean);
    ninpieces.reduce(function(obj, prop, index) {
      var curr = ninpieces[index + 1];
      if (!obj[prop] && !!curr) {
        obj[prop] = {
          [curr]: {}
        };
      } else {
        if (obj[prop] && curr && !obj[prop][curr]) {
          obj[prop][curr] = {}
        }
      }
      return obj[prop]
    }, stractureobj)
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll("pre")[1].textContent = JSON.stringify(stractureobj, null, 2)
```

```css
pre:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<pre>CITYS
CITYS.AREAS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.KITCHEN
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TV
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE.VASE
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE.ASTREY
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE.SHAMPOO
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE.CONTITIONER
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.POOL
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.POOL.WATER
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.TREE
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.BRAND
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.BRAND.LOGO
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.COLOR
CITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.TYPE
</pre>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help this answer Solved my problem :) !!! My next step is to export this object in HTML DOM like
          document.createElement("DIV"); for each nested obj but i have to declare somehow what type of element i want. I will try it and if i can't do it i will come up with an other question.
Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess in JS it's essential to have "dynamic" access to nested values both to get or set them. I think this is a missing functionality. So i decided to develop two reusable Object methods. They are `Object.prototype.getNestedValue()` and `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` They are very handy tools for these use cases and just turn your job nothing more than a very simple task. OK let's get into them to see what they are.

`setNestedValue()` takes a number of arguments. All arguments except the last one are used as object properties if it's a `"string"` type or array index if it's a `"number"` type. The last argument is the value of the last object property or array index at the very last in line. Accordingly.

```
var o = {};
o.setNestedValue("a",3,"b","value");
```

or

```
var o = {};
o.setNestedValue(...["a",3,"b"],"value");
```

are typical use cases. Lets see a simple example.

```js
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                       : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                          this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
               : this[a[0]] = a[1];
  return this;
};

var o = {};
o.setNestedValue("a",3,"x","value");
o.setNestedValue("a",2,"y","value");
o.setNestedValue("a",1,"z","value");
o.setNestedValue("a",0,"w","value");
console.log(JSON.stringify(o,null,2));
```

OK now it's the time for your solution;

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};

Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                       : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                          this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
               : this[a[0]] = a[1];
  return this;
};

var data = "CITYS\nCITYS.AREAS\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.KITCHEN\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TV\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE.VASE\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.LIVINGROOMS.TABLE.ASTREY\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE.SHAMPOO\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.ROOMS.BATHROOMS.BATHTUBE.CONTITIONER\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.POOL\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.POOL.WATER\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.HOUSES.GARDEN.TREE\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.BRAND\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.BRAND.LOGO\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.COLOR\nCITYS.AREAS.STREETS.CARS.TYPE",
  datarr = data.split("\n").map(e => e.split(".")), // get your list in an array
       o = {};
       datarr.forEach(a =>  o.setNestedValue(...a,""));
       console.log(JSON.stringify(o,null,2));
```

Allright.. that's it... It's so simple.