# javascript add dynamically properties in sub object

Tags: javascript, object

```
var Object = {
a : 1,
b : 2,
c : {
      d : 4,
      e : 5,
    }
}
```

Hello, i would like to add an property and his value as this  "Object.c.f = 6" dynamically with an function (i don't know 6 and f).

```
//is it possible in pure javascript ?
function add(f){
    object.c.f = f;
}
```

Comment: What you have works fine if the variable names were correct. Don't use `Object` as variable name. `var object` is fine and matches what use in the function.

Comment: You can do this with a 3rd party `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` method. Please see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368315/create-nested-object-which-contains-n-nested-objectsfrom-txt-file-javascript/37395701#37395701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/legends77/dzja15dd/):

```
var obj = {
a : 1,
b : 2,
c : {
      d : 4,
      e : 5,
    }
};

function add(name,val){
    obj.c[name] = val;
}

var n = "myprop";

add(n,10);

alert(obj.c[n]);
```

P.S.: Didn't check cross-browser compatability, works in Chrome v51